# TypeScript debugging issue 'Invalid cast' showing on my Mac only

Tags: macos, typescript, debugging, yarnpkg

Excuse my first use here but this debugger error doesn't show on the machines of my colleagues!

```
yarn start v0.17.8
$ ts-node ./src/engine/server/server /Users/aa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1325
return Debug.fail("Invalid cast. The supplied value " + value + " did not pass the test '" + Debug.getFunctionName(test) + "'.");
                 ^
Error: Debug Failure. Invalid cast. The supplied value [object Object] did not pass the test 'isJsonSourceFile'.
at Object.cast (/Users/aa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1325:22)
at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrPropertyWorker (/Users/aa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:35591:41)
at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrProperty (/Users/aa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:35567:48)
at getTypeOfSymbol (/Users/aa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:35856:24)
at getExternalModuleMember (/Users/aa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:32495:64)
at getTargetOfImportSpecifier (/Users/aa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:32530:20)
at getTargetOfAliasDeclaration (/Users/aa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:32562:28)
at resolveAlias (/Users/aa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:32595:30)
at checkAliasSymbol (/Users/aa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:55749:26)
at checkImportBinding (/Users/aa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:55778:13)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Using Node 6.10.3, Yarn and Mac (if any is relevant). 
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you updated to Typescript 3.2 recently?

Reverting to `3.1`, or even updating to `typescript@next` (i.e. the nightly builds) both address the issue.

It was raised in the Typescript Issue Tracker in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28762), and appears to of been patched, but not released yet by this [Pull Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28782).

Comment: Correct! Thanks!